# Touch to spinner activate system ui. Android

Tags: android, user-interface, system, android-spinner, status

```
public class CommentActivity extends Activity {

public TextView userNameText;
public ImageView italicTextImage;
public ImageView boldTextImage;
public EditText headerEditText;
public EditText messageEditText;
public Spinner availChooser;
public Button sendButton;
//--
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Typeface mainFont;
public Bundle extras;
public SharedPreferences appSettings;
//--
public static final int NEGATIVE_AVAIL = -1;
public static final int NEUTRAL_AVAIL = 0;
public static final int POSITIVE_AVAIL = 1;
private int selectedAvail = NEGATIVE_AVAIL;
//--
private String userName;
private String route;
private String articleId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Disable UI bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    //--
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);
    //--
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    appSettings = getSharedPreferences(Settings.APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    initTypeface();
    initViews();
    setActivity();
    //--
    availChooser.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    selectedAvail = NEGATIVE_AVAIL;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selectedAvail = NEUTRAL_AVAIL;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selectedAvail = POSITIVE_AVAIL;
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

In my Activity in the onCreate method I disable system ui. But when I touch to spinner, and list with items drop - system ui has activate. I tried disable ui in the spinner's onCklickListener, but it's does not help. How I can fix it?

Comment: Show the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Could you please share your java code? So that we can help what is the issue you are facing. Without code its hard to help you.

Comment: Are you meaning to say you're trying to make a full screen app but the notification bar keeps reappearing?

Comment: @ElefantPhace I'm make a full screen. But when I touch to spinner(only to spinner) - system ui makes visible again